# Can I answer without getting points?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have read the comments on this, but am not finding anything that really fits my question.

Sometime I write an answer that wouldn't fit well into a comment -- but the answer is so simple I would feel silly being awarded "points".  I'm here to a) be helpful b) learn.  Chasing points is not one of my goals, and I certainly don't need credit for solving a h.s. algebra problem.

Yet I occasionally answer such things, mainly because I think I can explain clearly.

This situation doesn't seem like a good fit for "community wiki", even if I can figure out how to put it there.  Yet somehow I'd like to tell the point machine not to bother with that answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Points can't hurt you. If you are not chasing points, why not just mentally ignore them if they are given to you?

Comment: I agree points can't hurt me.  And I do try to ignore them.  I guess I'm concerned people will wonder why I am answering an easy question when I could leave it to someone else. It really has to do with the level of confusion of the OP -- if he/she seems very lost I might be able to help.

Comment: This was listed among related questions: [How to post answer without gaining “reputation” points and without CW?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-to-post-answer-without-gaining-reputation-points-and-without-cw) An answer given there suggest bounties as a possibility.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I did read that one.  The problem seemed to be that the internal workings of the site promote bonus questions to the top.  So I would have to think up a bonus question to offer, one worthy of promotion.

Answer (score 11):

Using community wiki is the correct approach to post without earning any reputation. When you post an answer there is a checkbox "community wiki" below the text field on the right side.

Community wiki is often misused for the effect it has on reputation, even though that was not the original idea behind it. But I don't see any major problem in using it this way.

The one exception is using community wiki to post controversial answers that will be downvoted. CW allows you to evade the reputation penalty that you would usually suffer, so that could be declared a misuse of the feature. But that is not what you are after, so this would not be a problem.

The other option is to just ignore the reputation system, which is an equally valid choice in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think it's really abuse to evade downvotes with a controversial answer, if you actually believe the answer is a good and useful one. If it goes beyond controversial to inappropriate, then of course it will be flagged.